# Wordpress - show link to picture instead of the actual picture

Tags: php, html, wordpress

can someone tell me how i can display a link (with the title to the picture) on a wordpress page, instead of actual picture? 
so the tinymce of wordpress creates after i added a picture somethin like that:

```
<p><img src="url" alt=""/></p>
```

i want just this:

```
<p><a href="pictureUrl">wp title of the pic</a></p>
```

is this possible, is there maybe a plugin? Would be great if someone can help me.
Thx

Comment: You could... create a link to the image...? I believe the shortcut is CTRL+K, or just use the "Insert link" button/menu item.

Comment: why do you insert an image when you don't want to insert an image. Click insert `link` and enter the `url` to the image.

Comment: isnt there a more automatic way to add pictures?